# Two "like" queries combined and ordered

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I have a table "mytable" with a column "name".  I wish to query for all rows that start with a certain string or have the string somewhere in the name, and order them in a way that the rows that start with the name come first.  Is it possible to have just one query?

I cannot use "union", I'm using Hibernate and it is not supported.  I would prefer not to use views as they are not cached by Hibernate second level cache.

Comment: Why do you need Hibernate?  Why can't JDBC and straight SQL manage it?  Just because you're using Hibernate doesn't mean it has to be an all or none proposition.

Comment: try ordering by the `indexOf("certainString")`

Comment: dyffymo: I'm just stating my limitations due to requirements for my particular environment.  I could use two sql queries with hibernate or use a view or go native sql with hibernate but that would not be ideal in my situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps something like this could work?

```
select nvl(mytable1.name, '') || nvl(mytable2.name, '') as name, 
nvl(mytable1.i, '') || nvl(mytable2.i, '') as i from 
(select 1 as i, name from mytable where name like ('string%')) mytable1
full outer join
(select 2 as i, name from mytable where name like ('%string%')) mytable2
where (mytable1.name is null or mytable2.name is null)
and mytable1.name != mytable2.name
order by i, name
```

but I think I would have used one of the following:

- a simple query with union for this query
- a sort in Java instead, and do it as 2 queries.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you can do:

```
select *
  from myTable mt
 where mt.column like '%TargetString%'
 order by instr(mt.column, 'TargetString')
```

If you are using Hibernate + Oracle, it supports `instr` function in the dialect.

I believe other RDBMSs has similar functions too, which may be supported by Hibernate dialect.

Comment: I'm using MySQL..the question is tagged.  Thank you though.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit**: Since you have an aversion to leveraging more than one Criteria Query - for whatever reason - I would suggest reading up on the [Order](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Order.html) class.  It will not provide you with what you want.  That leaves you with few options.

One option would be to leverage [Hibernate Search](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.1/reference/en-US/html/).

Another would be to leverage Hibernate for the query and then `Collections.sort(...)` for your ordering.

```
List<MyObject> lstMyObject = ...;
Collections.sort(lstMyObject, new Comparator<MyObject>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
        // Assuming 'argument' is passed to this method and defined as 'final'
        return o1.getName().startsWith(argument) && o2.getName().startsWith(argument) ? 0 :
            o1.getName().startsWith(argument) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

This satisfies your requirement of 1) Using Hibernate, 2) Not using multiple queries, 3) Not using native SQL, 4) Not using views, 5) Not using a 'union'.

---

My advice would be two queries, something **like**:

```
public List<MyObject> findMyObjects(...) {
    Criteria queryStartsWith = sf.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(MyObject.class)
        .add(Restrictions.like("myProperty",nameArgument,MatchMode.START))
        .addOrder(Order.desc);

    Criteria queryLike = sf.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(MyObject.class)
        .add(Restrictions.like("myProperty",nameArgument,MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
        .addOrder(Order.desc);

    List<MyObject> lstMyObject = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    for (Object curObject : queryStartWith.list())
        if (curObject instanceOf MyObject)
            lstMyObject.add((MyObject) curObject);

    for (Object curObject : queryLike.list())
        if (curObject instanceOf MyObject)
            lstMyObject.add((MyObject) curObject);

    return lstMyObject;
}
```

I'm not sure Hibernate will accommodate your conditional Ordering.  The org.hibernate.criterion.Order class is pretty limited, to be honest.

Other than using native SQL, this is the only option I can think of off the top of my head.

Comment: I'm aware of the two query approach..asking for one..btw all of the looping and instance checks are completely unnecessary..queryStartsWith.list().add(queryLike.list()) will do

Comment: I apologize.  You didn't specify that you didn't want to use two Criteria Queries, just that you wanted to use Hibernate.  Whoever downvoted should get busy with the other answers.  At least this leverages Hibernate - which *was* requested - rather than reverting to native SQL.